Copilot and file-path autocomplete together in vscode
I'm using copilot in VScode. When I'm reading in files etc., copilot tries to complete file paths and names based on the comments. I want path completions to be based on the files on the system, like IDEs such as Rstudio do it. i.e., tab complete the path if there's only one object with the prefix I've already written, or even show a list as I'm typing. How do I get both copilot and path completion? Maybe there are different keybindings?

Hmm, currently even I'm trying to give instruction but there is no Function Calling technique applied to extract exact system file paths in the in-line suggestion. I believe that's a great idea for GitHub Copilot team to improve in the future...
